# Not able to add Background Image on Position Absolute div

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/3b2kh8gn/1/) and let me know why I am not able to add image to the `#img-box`

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#img-box {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("http://www.bluearthrenewables.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/7_Intake-Construction_CullitonCreek.jpg");
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `#img-box` has not any width & heights associated with it. try to define

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#img-box {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/0/f/b/13873752061098664878happy_smiley-th.png");
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="img-box"></div>
    <div id="tets"></div>
    <div id="tes3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the div dimensions using `right:0` and `bottom:0`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#img-box {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("http://www.bluearthrenewables.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/7_Intake-Construction_CullitonCreek.jpg");
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="img-box"></div>
  <div id="tets"></div>
  <div id="tes3"></div>
</div>
```